# Index file redirects in nginx

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm

**Scenario**

I have a website with the following structure:

```
/index.html
/about/index.html
/contact/index.php
/contact/send_email.php
```

I would have liked to make the URL's cleaner, so I would be the equivalent structure with:

```
/ => /index.html
/about/ => /about/index.html
/contact/ => /contact/index.html
/contact/send_email.php => /contact/send_email.php
```

Basically an Nginx configuration that removes all `index.html` or `index.php` file names from the URI.

**My Attempted Configuration**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /home/www/mysite;
    server_name www.mysite.com;        

    location ^~* /[a-z]+/index\.(html|php)$ {
        rewrite ^(/[a-z]+/)index\.(html|php)$ http://www.mysite.com$1? permanent;
    }

    try_files $uri $uriindex.html $uriindex.php =404;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5.sock
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

**The Problem**

In short - it doesn't work. When I go to `/about/index.html` it *should* permanently redirect to `/about/` but it just stays on `/about/index.html`. I have tested the regular expressions and they seem to be fine - i.e. the capturing group defined in the rewrite works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of nginx are you using?

I've tried your configuration with nginx 1.4.2 and it detected a few syntax errors:

1. `invalid location modifier "^~*"` in your first `location` directive - I changed it to `~`
2. `unknown "uriindex" variable` in your `try_files` directive - I changed both `$uriindex.html` and `$uriindex.php` to `$uri/index.html` and `$uri/index.php`

At this point I believe the setup does most of what you want:

1. Going to `www.mysite.com/about/index.html` you're redirected to `www.mysite.com/about/`
2. Going to `www.mysite.com/contact/index.html` you're redirected to `www.mysite.com/contact/`
3. Going to `www.mysite.com/contact/send_email.php` no redirect takes place

Now for `www.mysite.com/index.html` to redirect to `www.mysite.com/`, you'll need another "location" directive and rewrite rule:

```
location ~ /index\.html$ {
    rewrite ^/index\.html$ http://www.mysite.com permanent;
}
```

And as for `www.mysite.com/contact/` to be executed with PHP-FPM as `www.mysite.com/contact/index.php` script, you'll also need a specific location directive.  The `fastcgi_index index.php` line here is really important:

```
location = /contact/ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5.sock
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the changes. I am running nginx version 1.1.19. My only problem now is when I try to go to `/contact/index.php` it downloads the PHP page instead of running it through PHP-FPM. The `location ~\.php$` block doesn't seem to catch the `$uri/index.php` directive in `try_files`.

Comment: `location ~\.php$` doesn't catch `/contact/index.php` because its rewritten to `/contact/`.  You need one more `location` directive, I've updated the answer above to show this.

Comment: I thought about doing this originally, but I would have to add a new `location =/xxxx/` block for any directory with an `index.php`.